# How to get the rows where a column is at its maximum within each group in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

I have a huge table "trades". I need to get the rows where column "price" is at its maximum within each stock.

What I can think of is as follows:

```
t = select * from trades context by symbol order by price desc
select top 1 * from t context by symbol
```

I am wondering if this can be done with one line of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In DolphinDB, `csort` clause can work together with `context by` clause to specify the sorting columns within each context group.

```
select * from t context by symbol csort price desc limit 1
```